# Sort a list of objects

Tags: java, list, sorting, object, comparison

Is there such a method as follows I can use, so that I can pass any list of any objects and it will return a sorted list in the order I want?

**public List sort(List listToBeSorted, String order, String property){
}**

```
class Person{
    private String name;
    private Date dob;
    private int age; 
}
```

So if I call the above method like so:

```
sort(myList, "ascending", "name");
```

It will sort the list in ascending order of "name" property of the person object.

---

I tried using Comparator as follows but couldn't get it anywhere close to what I actually wanted.

```
   public class PersonComparator {
    public static final Comparator<Person> NAME_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<Person>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Person object1, Person object2) {            
            return object1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(object2.getName());
        }       
    };  
    public static final Comparator<Person> DOB_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<Person>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Person object1, Person object2) {
            return object1.getDob().compareTo(object2.getDob());
        }       
    };  
    public static final Comparator<Person> AGE_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<Person>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Person object1, Person object2) {
            return object1.getAge().compareTo(object2.getAge());
        }       
    };  
}
```

And used the comparator as follows:

```
List<Person> myList = new ArrayList<Person>();
Collections.sort(myList, PersonComparator.NAME_COMPARATOR);
```

**EDIT:**

The example I have given works fine. But It only works for Person class. I wanted a method that would work for any list of objects and I can specify what order I want as well as the property of the object to sort by.

Comment: There must be something wrong in your `Comparator` implementation then. Note that you can do more complex rules inside the `Comparator` implementation.

Comment: Well, that should work... Can you give example data where it does not?

Comment: How do you compare the fields in general? In a generic setting, how would you compare, say, two `HashMap`s?

Comment: My implementation works fine. But this comparator that I created works only for Person class and I have no way of specifying the order ie ascending or descending.

Comment: @ZiyaoWei `HashMap` doesn't care about `Comparable`; are you sure you didn't mean `TreeMap`?

Comment: There is no method similar to the one you ask about. But calling `Collections.sort()` as you describe can do the same thing if you pass it the right comparator. Note that a comparator can do ascending or descending based on whether you return the compare value on the strings or return the negative of that compare value.

Comment: @Susie yes you has. For descending order, just multiply the result of the comparison with -1. By the way, nice code that doesn't compile (like calling a `compareTo` method from an `int`).

Comment: In this case you'll have to create your own method; but reverse sorting is easy with an anonymous `Comparator` just returning the negative result of another one.

Comment: Note that your comparators will fail if any field value is null.

Comment: @fge If I am not mistaken (I might), the OP wants a generic comparison that might need reflection. However, if the two properties are two `Map`s, there is no clear way of comparing those two.

Comment: You can obtain a descending comparator using the [Collections.reverseOrder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder(java.util.Comparator)) method.  For instance: `Comparator<Person> DESCENDING_NAME_COMPARATOR = Collections.reverseOrder(NAME_COMPARATOR);`

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Bean Comparator](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/23/bean-comparator/).

> It will sort the list in ascending order of "name" property of the person object.

You can control the sort order, but you specify a method to access the property, not the property itself.

Comment: I tried using the BeanComparator from "org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanComparator". But BeanComparator doesn't have the constructor the blog suggests, the one that takes a class and string as parameters.

Answer (score 2):

For ascending and descending, you might use [`reverseOrder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder%28java.util.Comparator%29) to get a different `Comparator`. That is supported directly by Java, and is a rather standard method for achieving the effect of reversing the ordering.

If you want to use different fields base on a parameter, then you might need reflection to do it. Note you might want to check if the field [`isAssaignableFrom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29) `Comparable` before comparing the fields. Otherwise, you could choose to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` or something close.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement like this ...

```
class MyCompartor<E>{
    public Comparator<E> getCompartor(final String order,final String propertyName){

        return new Comparator<E>() {

                @Override
                public int compare(E o1, E o2) {
                        Class noparams[]={};
                        try {
                            char temp[] = propertyName.toCharArray();
                            temp[0] = Character.toUpperCase(temp[0]);
                            String tempName=new String(temp);
                            Method method = o1.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("get"+tempName, noparams);
                            Object val1 = method.invoke(o1, null);
                            Object val2 = method.invoke(o2, null);
                            if(order.equalsIgnoreCase("ascending"))
                            {
                                return ((Comparable)val1).compareTo(val2);
                            }else{
                                return ((Comparable)val2).compareTo(val1);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } 
                    return 0;
                }
            };
    }
}
```

and calling the sort like this

```
Collections.sort(list,new MyCompartor<Person>().getCompartor("ascending", "name"));
```

hope this helps ??
but mind you the property must return an object that is java.lang.Comparable

Comment: and that you need to implement getters :P